# How to set the declared value in fedex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fedex

I am using a old plugin for fedex in one of my `rails 2.3` application.

How can I set the declared value in `fedex`?

If in any other gems it can be possible, please give some reference and the code snippet where I need to point.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

EDIT

```
def fedex(options = {})
    get_session_data
    opt = FEDEX_DEFAULT_AUTH.merge(options)
    #opt.merge!({:dropoff_type => Fedex::ShipConstants::DropoffTypes::REQUEST_COURIER}) if @options.is_pickup?

    Fedex::Base.new(opt)
  end

  def fedex_shipment_options(service_type, is_residential_destination)

    ship_from_company = @ship_from.company.strip
    ship_to_company = @ship_to.company.strip

    shipper = {
        :name => [@ship_from.first_name, @ship_from.last_name].compact.join(' ').strip,
        :phone_number => @ship_from.phone.strip,
        :company => ['comp', ship_from_company].delete_if(&:blank?).join(' / ')
    }
    recipient = {
        :name => [@ship_to.first_name, @ship_to.last_name].compact.join(' ').strip,
        :phone_number => @ship_to.phone.strip
    }
    recipient.merge!(:company => ship_to_company) unless ship_to_company.blank?

    origin = {
        :street => @ship_from.address1,
        :street2 => @ship_from.address2,
        :city => @ship_from.city,
        :state => @ship_from.state,
        :zip => @ship_from.postal_code,
        :country => 'US'
    }
    destination = {
        :street => @ship_to.address1,
        :street2 => @ship_to.address2,
        :city => @ship_to.city,
        :state => @ship_to.state,
        :zip => @ship_to.postal_code,
        :country => 'US'
    }

    {
        :shipper => { :contact => shipper, :address => origin },
        :recipient => { :contact => recipient, :address => destination.merge(:residential => true) },
        :weight => @package.weight.to_i,
        :service_type => service_type,
        :residential => is_residential_destination,
        :special_shipping_options => @options,
        :packages => [{:length => @package.length.to_i,
                       :height => @package.height.to_i,
                       :width => @package.width.to_i,
                       :weight => @package.weight.to_i,
                       :delivery_confirmation => @options.delivery_confirmation,

                       :declared_value =>  @options.insurance_amount
                      }]

    }
  end
```

Comment: please show us some code.

Comment: @xlembouras : can you please mark the Editted code.

Comment: @Monk_Code : concern was to set the declared value not for fedex gem in rails only.

Answer (score 2):

FedEx has 2 main types of declarations - declared value for customs and declared value for the insurance.
I am not sure about rails coding specifically (I recommend that you refer to the PHP, Java, C#, VB.Net examples from FedEx developers site(http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/web-services/index.html)), but when sending the XML request to FedEx, if you wish to send the declared customs value, you should add under the main "RequestedShipment" tag/element something like:

```
<CustomsValue>
  <Currency>USD</Currency>
 <Amount>155.00</Amount>
</CustomsValue>
```

And for declared insured value:

```
<TotalInsuredValue>
  <Currency>USD</Currency>
  <Amount>150</Amount>
</TotalInsuredValue>
```

Here is a complete XML request example:
http://pastebin.com/wSHiqZYV